# Dr ou Dr. (com ou sem ponto no final)?

Tags: português-brasileiro, abreviações

Devo usar um ponto na abreviação para `Doutor`, Dr(.)?

Dr ou Dr. (com ou sem ponto no final)?

Fiz algumas pesquisas e entendi que o ponto não precisa ser usado em inglês Britânico mas é recomendado em inglês americano. E no Brasil?

Esta questão refere-se aos indivíduos que concluíram o Doutoramento.

Comment: Apenas um comentário: _Dr_, na língua inglesa, refere-se normalmente a um profissional que concluiu com sucesso o doutoramento. Quando o profissional é formado em medicina, a abreviação mais comum é _MD_, após o nome do indivíduo, e o _Dr_ é opcional.

Comment: Não tinha percebido este detalhe. Atualizei a questão para ser mais claro.

Answer (score 5):

No Brasil a forma com ponto, **Dr.**, é o que manda a tradição e é assim que eu e meus colegas recebemos nossa correspondência de órgãos oficiais como o Conselho Regional de Medicina, o Conselho Federal de Medicina, O Sindicato dos Médicos, A Academia Nacional de Medicina, etc. O meu Aurélio tem a entrada de "**Dr.**", assim com ponto. Informalmente, é muito frequente a forma sem o ponto e ninguém é multado por causa disso.